# Avoiding wildcard expansion in Bash loop

Tags: bash, list, shell, for-loop, wildcard

I want to use a list as parameter to a for-loop; but *with* double quotes, the list isn't understood as a list, and *without* quotes, the wildcards are evaluated to filenames.

```sh
A="a* b*"

for ex in "$A"; do
    echo "$ex";
done

for ex in $A; do
    echo "$ex";
done
```

The first one prints:

```
a* b*
```

The latter prints:

```
a.txt
b.txt
```

I want:

```
a*
b*
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: errr... I think I am becoming blind... what is the difference between the two loops?

Comment: thkala, agreed. Presumably one of them should NOT have $A surrounded with dbl-quotes. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `set -f` to disable pathname expansion:

```
A="a* b*"

( set -f
  for ex in $A ; do
      echo "$ex"
  done
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use an array:

```
A=("a*" "b*")
for ex in "${A[@]}"; do
    echo "$ex"
done
```

Comment: Typo: `for x` should be `for ex`